Mapped endpoint doesn't work when using attribute-routing ASP.NET
I hope you are doing OK, I have a project that I am updating and streamlining. BTW I am also learning .NET
I have the next problem, when I change this:
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapHub<NotificationsHub>("/hubs/notifications");
});

to this:
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapControllers();
app.MapRazorPages();

my attribute method in this controller stops working
public class OidcConfigurationController : Controller
    {
        ...

        [HttpGet("_configuration/{clientId}")]
        public IActionResult GetClientRequestParameters([FromRoute]string clientId)
        {   
             ...
        }
    }

I have tried adding more attributes, but it just never gets executed, but it continues being registered by Swuagger. I don't catch why is that I get the suggestion for using top level parameters if it breaks my routing.

Maybe this answer could help you. And I found this blog which also helps to understand.

We usually see app.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); within template project in MVC app and app.MapControllers(); within API project.
app.MapControllerRoute is called conventional routing because it establishes a convention for URL paths. It allows creating the app without having to come up with a new URL pattern for each action. So that we don't need to set [Route] attribute for each action as there's a default pattern.
While app.MapControllers is called to map attribute routed controllers, this is because REST APIs should use attribute routing to model the app's functionality as a set of resources where operations are represented by HTTP verbs. This requires developers to set attribute routing using [Route] attribute for each Controller/action.
In your scenario, I recommend you adding [Route("_configuration/{clientId}")][HttpGet] before the action method, to make it be accessible by a Get url.
